# Can I turn off swearing for my kids?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

My young kids have expressed interest in playing Heroes of the Storm, but I'm a little concerned about the swearing in the game. The [ESRB description](http://esrb.org/ratings/search.aspx?from=home&titleOrPublisher=heroes%20of%20the%20storm) contains swearing that I'd like to limit at their age. Mostly it seems to be banter / dialogue. Also, I've noticed Tycus swears, but I'm not sure when. Can that be turned off?

Comment: Are you talking about Diablo, Azmodan and the Diablo map announcers saying 'Hell' and 'Damn?' That's really as coarse as it gets, and they're talking about/are the forces of a literal Hell/the literal damned.

Comment: @Dallium the literal hell is more acceptable. I've edited the post to be more clear.

Comment: Hm, I cannot recall even Tychus swearing.  I know Starcraft has dialogue of that nature.  Are you positive you have heard it in Heroes?

Comment: @Jerry Tycus swearing I have heard has been along the lines of the non-literal "hell", but I'm more worried about the other words in the ESRB description.

Comment: I seem to recall hearing those words within the game's first year of release, but it was a rare occurrence, which is why I cannot recall it very well now.  I think Blizzard revamped some of the dialogue, especially with the version 2 release, to remove questionable dialogue.  In version 2, you can sample/hear every characters' dialogue.  While I have not tested all, I really cannot recall hearing the words from the ESRB summary, which is probably not updated unless Blizzard makes a request.

Comment: @jerry, I think this is the best answer yet.

Comment: The real issue is that especially among the inexperienced players (the ones your kids will be matched with in the first 100-500 or so games) there's very often at least 1 person in chat with a very foul mouth and no manners. I recommend to disable allied chat at least until they reach a skill level where the flamers don't compete anymore.

Comment: @Peter Yeah, I'm aware of the chat problems, but this is about the in-game announcer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Mature Language Filter option in the game. You can enable it by opening the options menu, selecting the "Social" tab and then checking the box labeled "enable mature language filter".

Note: I am basing this on the following video:

. It might be possible that the options have changed since then.

Comment: Personally I would recommend turning off chat all together.  There's  the inherit problem of mature languages filters only censoring specific words but then people either find loopholes on how to say certain words or just find derogatory terms that aren't censored.  Even though I'm okay hearing curse words and other offensive language I have chat disabled because chat is just filled with angry people 90% of the time.

Comment: I'm not concerned about chat language. I was previously aware of this, and other features to limit chat. I'm trying to eliminate swearing by characters in game.

Comment: @McKay, have you heard an example phrase? can you identify which character says it?

Comment: @jerry I've edited the question to answer these questions.

Answer (score 1):

As Nzall states, there is a mature language filter for chat to censor things your teammates say, however I believe you are specifically referring to the announcer's voice lines. If you got to Options -> Sounds, you can disable/turn off the announcer by clicking the check mark next to it. Most of the things the announcer states also have visual cues as well, so you won't be lacking too much, you will just have to pay more attention to the screen.

There also a set of new announcers that you can unlock from boxes or with shards. I haven't used one yet, however they may have different voice lines, and there may be one who doesn't swear, or swears less. This may be a better option if you can find such an announcer as you will still have the audio cues and won't have the swearing.

Comment: From the default announcer, I have not heard any swearing.  Can you give an example?